# Apply translation vector to polyline

Tags: c#, wpf, polyline

In my WPF application I want to add a vector v(a,b) to each vertex in a System.Windows.Shapes.Polyline. What I am currently doing is

```
Point v = new Point(a,b);
Polyline p = ....
for (int i=0; int < p.Points.Count(); ++i)
{
   p.Points[i] = new Point(p.Points[i].x + v.x, p.Points[i].y + v.y);
}
```

This however feels ridiculously heavyweight. However I could not find a proper method for this simple task.

Answer (score 1):

You would usually put the Polyline in a Canvas and set its `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties.

The following assumes that `p` is a child element of a Canvas, and that `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` have been set to some initial values (e.g. `0`):

```
Polyline p = ...
Canvas.SetLeft(p, Canvas.GetLeft(p) + a);
Canvas.SetTop(p, Canvas.GetTop(p) + b);
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but IIRC the canvas top & left properties for a polyline does not affect the coordinates for the point collection in the polyline.

Comment: That's right. The polyline coordinates are relative to the Polyline element, while Left and Top place the Polyline relative to the Canvas.